Do Google Analytics events_intraday_$date tables get deleted from Big Query?
We are using the Big Query export from Google Analytics.  The export type is Streaming (we don't have Daily checked).  Do the events_intraday_$date tables ever get deleted when Daily is not enabled?
We have over 1M events and can't afford the Analytics 360 service.  We would like to use the data in events_intraday for long term reporting. 3+ years of data.  Is this possible?

No, they shouldn't be deleted. BQ has a weird way of showing tables though. Every day even in streaming will be partitioned in its own table. event_intraday_(200) means there are 200 tables/days. BQ won't delete tables on it's own.

No, they don't delete intraday tables unless they replace them with the events table. For your issue, you can uncheck the daily export in GA4 config, and also keep the streaming option.

The result should be tables that look like the image below.
